# Dealing with Microphone and Speakers using C#

Tags: c#, rtp, multimedia

I need to make a voice chat using RTP multicast protocol ,So i need a C# dll library that can deal with speakers and microphone to get the user sound and send it over the network.
Recommend to be simple and very simple library with simple example using c#.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This seems not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question) to me. If you have a specific programming problem, please ask. You can read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using NAudio.dll library , we can dealing with microphone and speakers using C#  the following code:
1- This code will give us the microphone devices.

```
        List<NAudio.Wave.WaveInCapabilities> sources = new List<NAudio.Wave.WaveInCapabilities>();
        for (int i = 0; i < NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.DeviceCount; i++)
        {
            sources.Add(NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.GetCapabilities(i));
        }
        sourceListView.Items.Clear();

        foreach (var source in sources)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(source.ProductName);
            item.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, source.Channels.ToString()));
            sourceListView.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

2- This code will start capturing audio from the microphone and bring it out  to speakers.

```
    private NAudio.Wave.WaveIn sourceStream = null;
    private NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut waveOut = null;

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sourceListView.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return;
        //NAudio.Wave.MixingWaveProvider32 mixer=sourceStream.GetMixerLine();
        int deviceNumber = sourceListView.SelectedItems[0].Index;
        sourceStream = new NAudio.Wave.WaveIn();
        sourceStream.DeviceNumber = deviceNumber;
        sourceStream.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(9600,8, NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.GetCapabilities(deviceNumber).Channels);
        NAudio.Wave.WaveInProvider waveIn = new NAudio.Wave.WaveInProvider(sourceStream);
        waveOut = new NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut();
        waveOut.Init(waveIn);
        sourceStream.StartRecording();
        sourceStream.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs>(sourceStream_DataAvailable);
        waveOut.Play();
    }

    void sourceStream_DataAvailable(object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (waveOut != null)
        {
            waveOut.Stop();
            waveOut.Dispose();
            waveOut = null;
        }
        if (sourceStream != null)
        {
            sourceStream.StopRecording();
            sourceStream.Dispose();
            sourceStream = null;
        }
    }
```

It is a very simple example to to do this issue, and You can download the NAudio.dll library from this website:
http://naudio.codeplex.com/releases/view/79035